# Why the label does not show completely in the scrollview?

Tags: python, kivy

The problem is like this:

I would like to write a paragraph(within a box layout because I may add some images) in a scroll view.

In kivy:

```
#:import ScrollEffect  kivy.effects.scroll.ScrollEffect
ScrollView:###info####
    effect_cls: ScrollEffect
    size_hint_x: 0.8
    bar_width: 10
    scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
    BoxLayout:
        id: notes_content
        spacing: 25
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: (1, None)
        height: sum([c.height for c in self.children])
        padding: (20, 100, 20, 0) #left, top, right, bottom
```

In py:

```
n_widget = Label(text=text_note,color=(0,0,0,1),halign='left', size_hint_y= None)
n_widget.bind(width=lambda s, w:s.setter('text_size')(s, (w, None)))
n_widget.bind(texture_size=n_widget.setter('size'))
```

As a result, it shows like

[image: this].

It is over the scroll view and what can I do to let it just fix to the right position??

Comment: What if you remove your `height=400` in your label and the `height: sum( ...)` in your scrollview?

Comment: height: sum(...) can't be removed because it determines how long you can scroll.

Comment: And the height=400 lets the label in a correct position, but I don't want the height to be fixed because I may change to a longer text of the label. So, I put like this 'n_widget.bind(width=lambda s, w:s.setter('text_size')(s, (w, None)))
n_widget.bind(texture_size=n_widget.setter('size'))', the height of label will be changed according to how long the text is.